# Speed up search file using Multithreading or Parallel.ForEach

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, parallel.foreach

I wrote a code to search for files and folders and (to check all possible combinations of inserted words) I have a sub that gives all permutations of the inserted strings.

My problem is that I'm repeating the code for every permutated string (for 4 words it means 24 times) and I'm trying to use `MultiThreading` to speed up the code.

I've read a lot of examples but I wasn't able to really understand the logic for many reasons (some examples were in C; any example was wrote with different logic)

I've tried with

```
Parallel.For  
Parallel.ForEach 
ThreadPool
```

but I wasn't able to wait all threads before setting the List (containig all results) as datasource of a listbox.

My code logic is:
Get words by splitting the search string
If search type is "all words in any order" then I get all permutations
I start searching for each of permutated strings

I don't like to add too much code to a question but I think it's necessary in this case to know how I'm working:

```
Private Sub Btn_Search_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_Search.Click
    Select Case True
        Case RBtn_Exact.Checked
            StartSearch(Me.TB_Pattern.Text.Trim)
        Case RBtn_AllInOrder.Checked
            Dim Pattern As String = ""
            For Each Word As String In Me.TB_Pattern.Text.Split(New Char() {" "c})
                If Word.Trim <> "" Then Pattern &= "*" & Word.Trim
            Next
            Pattern &= "*"
            StartSearch(Pattern)
            endsearch()
        Case RBtn_AllWithoutOrder.Checked
            Dim WordHash As New HashSet(Of String)
            For Each Word As String In Split(Me.TB_Pattern.Text, " ")
                If Word.Trim <> "" Then WordHash.Add(Word.Trim)
            Next
            If WordHash.Count > 5 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Max 5 words allowed for this kind of search", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
                Exit Sub
            End If
            'Get permutations into an array
            StringPermutations()
            'I need to add "*" at the end of each permutated string
            For S As Integer = 0 To PermutationsArr.Length - 1
                PermutationsArr(S) &= "*"
            Next
            'This is for searching without MultiThreading
            For Each Pattern As String In PermutationsArr
                StartSearch(Pattern)
            Next
            'This is my last test
            'Parallel.ForEach(PermutationsArr,
            '                    Sub(Pattern)
            '                        StartSearch(Pattern)
            '                    End Sub
            '                 )
            'Task.WaitAll()
            endsearch()
        Case RBtn_AnyWord.Checked
            Dim WordHash As New HashSet(Of String)
            For Each Word As String In Split(Me.TB_Pattern.Text, " ")
                If Word.Trim <> "" Then WordHash.Add(Word.Trim)
            Next
            If WordHash.Count > 5 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Max 5 words allowed for this kind of search", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
                Exit Sub
            End If
            For Each Word As String In WordHash
                StartSearch(pattern:="*" & Word & "*")
            Next
            endsearch()
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub StartSearch(ByVal pattern As String)
    'Search for files
    If Me.CBox_Files.Checked Then
        FileSearch(Me.TB_StartFolder.Text, pattern)
    End If
    'Search for folders
    If Me.CBox_Folders.Checked Then
        ProcessDir(Me.TB_StartFolder.Text, pattern)

        DirSearch(Me.TB_StartFolder.Text, pattern)
    End If
End Sub

Sub endsearch()
    Me.Btn_Search.Text = "Start"
    Me.Btn_Search.BackColor = Me.BackColor
    If Me.LB_Files.Items.Count > 0 Then
        Me.Lbl_FilesFound.Text = Me.LB_Files.Items.Count.ToString
        Me.Lbl_FilesFound.Visible = True
    End If
    If Me.LB_Folders.Items.Count > 0 Then
        Me.Lbl_DirFound.Text = Me.LB_Folders.Items.Count.ToString
        Me.Lbl_DirFound.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub

Sub DirSearch(ByVal sDir As String, ByVal Pattern As String)
    Try
        For Each Dir As String In Directory.GetDirectories(sDir)
            Try
                For Each D As String In Directory.GetDirectories(Dir, Pattern)
                    Try
                        If LimitReached(LB_Folders) Then
                            Me.Lbl_LimitReached.Visible = True
                            Exit Sub
                        Else
                            If Me.CBox_Folders.Checked AndAlso Not LB_Folders.Items.Contains(D) Then LB_Folders.Items.Add(D)
                        End If
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        Continue For
                    End Try
                Next
                DirSearch(Dir, Pattern)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Continue For
            End Try
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
Sub FileSearch(ByVal sDir As String, ByVal Pattern As String)
    Dim d As String = ""
    Try
        For Each f As String In Directory.GetFiles(sDir, Pattern)
            Try
                If LimitReached(LB_Files) Then
                    Me.Lbl_LimitReached.Visible = True
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    If Me.CBox_LastModRange.Checked Then
                        If Me.CBox_Files.Checked AndAlso IntoRangeDate(f) AndAlso Not LB_Files.Items.Contains(f) Then LB_Files.Items.Add(f)
                    Else
                        If Me.CBox_Files.Checked AndAlso Not LB_Files.Items.Contains(f) Then LB_Files.Items.Add(f)
                    End If
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                Continue For
            End Try
        Next
        'Search for subfolders
        For Each d In Directory.GetDirectories(sDir)
            Try
                ProcessDir(d, Pattern)
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
            Try
                FileSearch(d, Pattern)
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        Next
    Catch excpt As System.Exception
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub ProcessDir(d As String, ByVal Pattern As String)
    Try
        For Each f As String In Directory.GetFiles(d, Pattern)
            Try
                If LimitReached(LB_Files) Then
                    Me.Lbl_LimitReached.Visible = True
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    If Me.CBox_LastModRange.Checked Then
                        If Me.CBox_Files.Checked AndAlso IntoRangeDate(f) AndAlso Not LB_Files.Items.Contains(f) Then LB_Files.Items.Add(f)
                    Else
                        If Me.CBox_Files.Checked AndAlso Not LB_Files.Items.Contains(f) Then LB_Files.Items.Add(f)
                    End If
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                Continue For
            End Try
        Next
    Catch ex As System.Exception
    End Try
    Try
        For Each d In Directory.GetDirectories(d, Pattern)
            Try
                If Me.CBox_Folders.Checked AndAlso Not LB_Folders.Items.Contains(d) Then LB_Folders.Items.Add(d)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Continue For
            End Try
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

**EDIT**
Below my code for getting permutations (I know it has a particular logic but it works and it seems enough fast):

```
Private Sub StringPermutations()
    Try
        Dim WordHash As New HashSet(Of String)
        For Each Word As String In Split(Me.TB_Pattern.Text, " ")
            If Word.Trim <> "" Then WordHash.Add(Word.Trim)
        Next
        Dim WordList As List(Of String) = WordHash.ToList
        ReDim PermutationsArr(Factorial(WordList.Count) - 1)
        AddString(WordList, 0)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Function Factorial(ByVal Num As Integer) As Integer
    Try
        If Num > 0 AndAlso Num < 12 Then
            Dim Result As Int32 = 1
            Do
                Result *= Num
                Num -= 1
            Loop Until Num <= 1
            Return Result
        Else
            Return 0
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function

Private Sub AddString(ByVal WordList As List(Of String), ByVal StartId As Integer)
    Try
        Dim InsLoop As Integer = Factorial(WordList.Count - 1)
        If InsLoop = 0 Then InsLoop = 1
        For Each Word As String In WordList
            For InsWord As Integer = 1 To InsLoop
                PermutationsArr(StartId + InsWord - 1) &= "*" & Word
            Next
            If WordList.Count > 1 Then
                Dim Remaining As New List(Of String)
                For Each RemWord As String In WordList
                    If RemWord <> Word Then Remaining.Add(RemWord)
                Next
                AddString(Remaining, StartId)
            End If
            StartId += InsLoop
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: You could probably simplify things greatly - perhaps to the point of not needed parallel processing using linq.  If the logic to test if a file matches was isolated in on sub, something like this might work:  `Dim files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(startpath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(Function(w) FileMatches(w)).ToArray`.  Where `FileMatches()` would be a method to test if the conditions apply.  If one condition is file extension, set that in the `EnumerateFiles` call so NET filters them for you.

Comment: @Plutonix I'll test your suggest. Anyway I've already tryed without recursive code but my attempts didn't return all files

Comment: It is hard to discern all the rules and conditions you are dealing with from the code, so you might end up running something like that on different folders and merging the results. It does seem like it could be simplified though...

Comment: I found your question interesting so I whipped up an app that I think does what you're after. `AllWithoutOrder` is the one that takes the longest. Searching 5 words against a folder that has 125,323 Files, 12,443 Folders completes in 2 minutes. Is that on par with what you're getting?

Comment: @MrGadget First, thanks For your time. I didn't unerstand what you mean: Have you modified my code or have you used a different code? I'm trying to "study" on these links: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462679(v=vs.110).aspx   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff477033(v=vs.110).aspx but I'm (still) not Able to use these logics into my code.

Comment: You should understand that the File I/O are the most expensive operations, so ` For Each Pattern ... StartSearch(Pattern)` is the wrong approach. You really need a method that reads the files once and can look for multiple patterns in them. And then parallelization will probably not help much. That would depend mostly on your disk hardware.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I tried taking a snapshot first, but it takes over 4 minutes to get all 125,323 file paths and 12,443 folder paths. That becomes a fixed time cost regardless of the pattern or how many matches there are. The answer I posted below is faster by miles. Searching `AllWithoutOrder` for `a b c d e` took less than 2 minutes. Two-word searches are done in 10-12 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my Form class, based on yours but substantially simplified. I used Tasks for multithreading, ConcurrentDictionarys to capture the results with capacity limits, concurrency levels, and without duplicates, and populate the Listboxes in one call at the end to minimize UI updates and the associated slowness. Concurrency level is the number of tasks that will be spawned to feed the ConcurrentDictionary.

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class SearchForm
    Private FoldersList As Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary(Of String, Object)
    Private FilesList As Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary(Of String, Object)

    Private Tasks As New List(Of Task)
    Private Words As New List(Of String)

    Private StopWatch As New Stopwatch

    ' Capacity of the ConcurrentDictionary objects
    ' Set this from user input on form to limit # of results returned
    Private Capacity As Int32 = 0

    Private PermutationsArr() As String = Nothing

    Private Sub Btn_Search_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_Search.Click
        Btn_Search.Text = "Wait"

        ' Capacity of the ConcurrentDictionary objects
        ' Set this from user input on form to limit # of results returned
        Capacity = 10000

        Tasks.Clear()
        Words.Clear()

        LB_Folders.DataSource = Nothing
        LB_Files.DataSource = Nothing

        Me.Refresh()

        StopWatch.Restart()

        Words.AddRange(Regex.Split(Regex.Replace(Me.TB_Pattern.Text.Trim, "\*", String.Empty), "\s+"))

        Select Case True
            Case String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Me.TB_Pattern.Text.Trim)
                MsgBox("Too few words", vbOKOnly, "Oops")
            Case Words.Count < 1
                MsgBox("Too few words", vbOKOnly, "Oops")
            Case Words.Count > 5
                MsgBox("Too many words", vbOKOnly, "Oops")

            Case Me.CBox_LastModRange.Checked AndAlso Me.DT_ModRangeEnd.Value < Me.DT_ModRangeStart.Value
                MsgBox("Range Start must precede Range End", vbOKOnly, "Oops")

            Case Me.RBtn_Exact.Checked
                FoldersList = New Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary(Of String, Object)(1, Capacity)
                FilesList = New Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary(Of String, Object)(1, Capacity)

                With Join(Words.ToArray)
                    If Me.CBox_Folders.Checked Then
                        ' NOTE: SearchFolders will evaluate CBox_Files.Checked and do SearchFiles if True
                        SearchFolders(Me.TB_StartFolder.Text, .ToString, True)
                    Else
                        ' NOTE: Only call SearchFiles from here if NOT doing SearchFolders
                        If Me.CBox_Files.Checked Then
                            SearchFiles(Me.TB_StartFolder.Text, .ToString, True, True)
                        End If
                    End If
                End With

            Case Me.RBtn_AllInOrder.Checked
                FoldersList = New Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary(Of String, Object)(1, Capacity)
                FilesList = New Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary(Of String, Object)(1, Capacity)

                With String.Format("*{0}*", Join(Words.ToArray, "*"))
                    If Me.CBox_Folders.Checked Then
                        ' NOTE: SearchFolders will evaluate CBox_Files.Checked and do SearchFiles if True
                        SearchFolders(Me.TB_StartFolder.Text, .ToString, True)
                    Else
                        ' NOTE: Only call SearchFiles from here if NOT doing SearchFolders
                        If Me.CBox_Files.Checked Then SearchFiles(Me.TB_StartFolder.Text, .ToString, True, True)
                    End If
                End With

            Case Me.RBtn_AllWithoutOrder.Checked
                StringPermutations()

                ' Math.Min caps the concurrency level at 40
                FoldersList = New Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary(Of String, Object)(Math.Min(40, PermutationsArr.Count), Capacity)
                FilesList = New Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary(Of String, Object)(Math.Min(40, PermutationsArr.Count), Capacity)

                For Each Pattern As String In PermutationsArr
                    If Me.CBox_Folders.Checked Then
                        ' NOTE: SearchFolders will evaluate CBox_Files.Checked and do SearchFiles if True
                        SearchFolders(Me.TB_StartFolder.Text, Pattern, True)
                        'Tasks.Add(Task.Run(Sub() SearchFolders(Me.TB_StartFolder.Text, Pattern)))
                    Else
                        ' NOTE: Only call SearchFiles from here if NOT doing SearchFolders
                        If Me.CBox_Files.Checked Then SearchFiles(Me.TB_StartFolder.Text, Pattern, True, True)
                    End If
                Next

            Case Me.RBtn_AnyWord.Checked
                FoldersList = New Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary(Of String, Object)(Words.Count, Capacity)
                FilesList = New Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary(Of String, Object)(Words.Count, Capacity)

                For Each Word In Words
                    With String.Format("*{0}*", Word)
                        If Me.CBox_Folders.Checked Then
                            ' NOTE: SearchFolders will evaluate CBox_Files.Checked and do SearchFiles if True
                            SearchFolders(Me.TB_StartFolder.Text, .ToString, True)
                        Else
                            ' NOTE: Only call SearchFiles from here if NOT doing SearchFolders
                            If Me.CBox_Files.Checked Then SearchFiles(Me.TB_StartFolder.Text, .ToString, True, True)
                        End If
                    End With
                Next
        End Select

        Task.WaitAll(Tasks.ToArray)

        Debug.Print("Tasks Completed in {0}", StopWatch.Elapsed.ToString)

        Debug.Print("Adding {0} Folders", FoldersList.Keys.Count.ToString)
        Me.LB_Folders.DataSource = FoldersList.Keys

        Debug.Print("Adding {0} Files", FilesList.Keys.Count.ToString)
        Me.LB_Files.DataSource = FilesList.Keys

        Btn_Search.Text = "Search"
    End Sub

    Private Sub SearchFolders(FolderPath As String, Pattern As String, Optional FirstCall As Boolean = False)
        Try
            Dim Folders() As String = IO.Directory.GetDirectories(FolderPath)

            For Each Folder As String In Folders
                Dim SubFolders() As String = IO.Directory.GetDirectories(Folder, Pattern)

                For Each SubFolder As String In SubFolders
                    Select Case True
                        Case Not FilesList.Count < Capacity
                            Exit For
                        Case Not Me.CBox_LastModRange.Checked
                            FoldersList.TryAdd(SubFolder, Nothing)
                        Case FolderInModRange(Folder)
                            FoldersList.TryAdd(SubFolder, Nothing)
                    End Select
                Next

                If Me.CBox_Files.Checked Then
                    ' Do NOT call this with Recursive = True from here!
                    SearchFiles(Folder, Pattern)
                End If

                If FirstCall Then
                    ' Perform multithreaded Recursion
                    Tasks.Add(Task.Run(Sub() SearchFolders(Folder, Pattern)))
                Else
                    ' Perform deep recursion within task thread...don't branch further
                    SearchFolders(Folder, Pattern)
                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException
            ' Access Denied
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print("SearchFiles: {0}", ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub SearchFiles(FolderPath As String, Pattern As String, Optional Recursive As Boolean = False, Optional FirstCall As Boolean = False)
        ' Recursive and FirstCall should only be True if NOT doing SearchFolders
        ' Recursive should only be True if called from the main thread or this method to continue the deep dive
        ' FirstCall should only be True if called from the main thread

        Try
            For Each Filename As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(FolderPath, Pattern)
                Select Case True
                    Case Not FilesList.Count < Capacity
                        Exit For
                    Case Not Me.CBox_LastModRange.Checked
                        FilesList.TryAdd(Filename, Nothing)
                    Case FileInModRange(Filename)
                        FilesList.TryAdd(Filename, Nothing)
                End Select
            Next

            If Recursive Then
                Try
                    Dim Folders() As String = IO.Directory.GetDirectories(FolderPath)
                    For Each Folder As String In Folders
                        If FirstCall Then
                            ' Perform multithreaded Recursion
                            Tasks.Add(Task.Run(Sub() SearchFiles(Folder, Pattern, Recursive)))
                        Else
                            ' Perform deep recursion within task thread...don't branch further
                            SearchFiles(Folder, Pattern, Recursive)
                        End If
                    Next
                Catch ex As Exception
                    ' Access Denied - Does this happen?
                    Debug.Print("Recursive FolderPath: {0}", ex.Message)
                End Try
            End If
        Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException
            ' Access Denied
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print("SearchFiles: {0}", ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Function FolderInModRange(Folder As String) As Boolean
        Try
            With New IO.DirectoryInfo(Folder)
                Select Case True
                    Case .LastWriteTime < Me.DT_ModRangeStart.Value
                        Return False
                    Case .LastWriteTime > Me.DT_ModRangeEnd.Value
                        Return False
                    Case Else
                        Return True
                End Select
            End With
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print("FolderInModRange: {0}{1}{2}", Folder, Environment.NewLine, ex.ToString)
        End Try

        ' Only if exception is thrown
        Return False
    End Function

    Private Function FileInModRange(Filename As String) As Boolean
        Try
            With New IO.FileInfo(Filename)
                Select Case True
                    Case .LastWriteTime < Me.DT_ModRangeStart.Value
                        Return False
                    Case .LastWriteTime > Me.DT_ModRangeEnd.Value
                        Return False
                    Case Else
                        Return True
                End Select
            End With
        Catch ex As IO.PathTooLongException
            ' Path Too Long
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print("FileInModRange: {0}{1}{2}", Filename, Environment.NewLine, ex.ToString)
        End Try

        ' Only if exception is thrown
        Return False
    End Function
End Class
```

Recursion avoids the `UnauthorizedAccessException` errors generated by .Net's `GetDirectories` and `GetFiles` methods when they run into folders that the user doesn't have access rights to.

References:

- [Task-based Asynchronous
  Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Concurrent
  Collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I'm trying to start using only a little part of your code (tasks), so  I'm using `For Each Pattern As String In PermutationsArr` (as array of strings) and `Tasks.Add(Task.Run(Sub() SearchFolders(Pattern)))` but I get this error: `Error BC30518 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Run' can be called with these arguments:
    'Public Shared Overloads Function Run(Of TResult)([function] As Func(Of TResult)) As Task(Of TResult)': Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) cannot be inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error.`

Comment: My `StringPermutations` is a `Sub` that populates an `array of strings`. If you want I'll edit my question adding that code

Comment: @genespos: Did you include my `Sub SearchFolders` ?

Comment: At the moment no, because to use your answer I need to change permutations code because mine gives an `array of strings` but you yours gives a `list(of list(of string))`. This was the reason to ask if you want to see my permutation code

Comment: I modified my code to run your answer as is but I got `'System.AggregateException' in mscorlib.dll` at `T.Wait()` so I removed the relative `with` block. I added `Task.WaitAll(Tasks.ToArray)`before giving a `DataSource` to `ListBoxes`. But I'll be grateful if you could explain me how to use `Tasks` on my original code because, with your code, I get errors if forbidden folders are found during searching. Eg. if I search starting from `C:\Users\PC\Documents\VB_Net_Examples` all works but  if I search starting from `C:\Users\PC\Documents` I get errors because of forbidden folders (I'm on win7)

Comment: @genespos I've applied a few changes to make it easier. Click the Edited link to see the revisions. I shouldn't have included the ProgressBar1 loop...`Task.WaitAll(Tasks.ToArray)` was the right replacement. `On Error Resume Next` is needed in 2 places to deal with the permissions errors, as stated in the answer (at some revision I took them out by accident).

Comment: Crap this needs a recursion to circumvent the Access Denied issue. Testing a solution...stand by.

Comment: I'm sure you're able to write a better code but mine already does this I only have problems on understanding how to use `task`. I'm looking for a good book, in the meantime, any links to tutorials (done well) is welcome

Comment: Final version update, including references, better matching your original, with recursion and comments.

Comment: I'll test it Tomorrow but you were really helpful so I want to thank you by now: accepted and +1